# Cannot upgrade python on vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, version

[image]

As shown in the photo, I've installed python 3.9.1, but the vs code IDE is working on python 2.7.16. I tried choosing the last version from the interpreter, but it didn't work.
So can someone help me, please?

Note(pip doesn't work because it is working on an old python version)

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: solution I guess is to not use vs code for editing

Comment: @rv.kvetch how is that a solution? Anyway the issue is that you've activated a custom virtualenv in the terminal, so it's not using the one that you've set VSCode to use (that's why you see `(base)` on every command line)

Comment: In this instance, I think the image is necessary to answer this because it's showing the whole setup (that they're using the terminal, that they've set the VSCode python env, and that they are trying to pull in a different environment). Showing the terminal output as text would make this _less_ easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

There are two different things happening here. Yes, VS code would use Pythnon 3.9.1 as it shows in the status bar. This will apply if you try to run/debug Python code from VS code using that > button with the bug next to it.

The terminal is another matter. Default Python on macOS is 2.7. If you want to run new Python in the terminal, you may just try

```
python3.9
```

or perhaps simply

```
python3
```

Edit

As was pointed by @roganjosh, you are using the "base" miniconda environment.

But still you get python 2.7. You may try to run

```
which python
```

to find out where exactly your python interpreter is. With that environment being active I would expect it to be in **/User/omararouf/miniconda3/bin/python**. But the system default would be in **/usr/bin/python**

Comment: I think you're incorrect on the second point. They're _actively_ activating a different environment from `conda`, which is just going to override whatever VSCode would be using, as configured

Comment: Yes, but something must be wrong with that environment and it is still defaults to the system Python (2.7)

Comment: Why must there be something _wrong_ with that environment? Maybe it was configured to use 2.7? The environment activated in the terminal is nothing at all to do with VSCode. `python3` will point to python 3 on the system level, but that says nothing about how they configured this specific virtualenv

Comment: Are you aware of [conda environments](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands)? I think you're getting that confused with the system installation

Comment: I don't have the "mini" conda, but when I run my `anaconda3/bin/activate` I get Python 3.6.8. I think it's unlikely that hte base conda envrionment would use 2.7.

Comment: Ah, the fact that it's `base` is indeed a good shout. We can't rule out that they didn't install the Python 2 version, though. There's a growing list of unknowns - why activate it in the first place inside the VSCode terminal?

Comment: Well, thanks a lot for your help, really appreciate it. Just tried
`(base) MrPrince-MacBook:~ omarmarouf$ python3.9
Python 3.9.0 (v3.9.0:9cf6752276, Oct  5 2020, 11:29:23) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
`
But have no idea what I should do after, I realize that vs code is running python 3.9 but the terminal isn't. But When I use me terminal (not the one in vs code) it actually says that I have python 3.9.1 
`(base) MrPrince-MacBook:~ omarmarouf$ python --version
Python 3.9.6`
So how can I fix this?

Comment: @OmarOshiba Try this: File > Preferences > Settings > (user or workspace) > extentions > Python > Python: Conda Path > enter the path to the Conda executable (not the environment).

Comment: @OmarOshiba, you can also try to compare the values of the PATH variable in both terminals - system and VS Code, before and after you activate your base conda environment. Perhaps it will give you some insights.